# ASP.NET error on Bitmap.Save "Exception (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap, drawing, gdi+

I have a function which first reads an image from disk, resizes it and then saves to another directory.

when i use the Bitmap.Save(directory + theimagename) it returns the error as i stated in the question title.

i checked the directory is right, and the given image name doesn't exist in that dir.

what is weird, is that the same code works great on the local machine. but when i upload it to my shared hosting space, it just doesn't work.

the code is below.

```
bmpOut = new Bitmap(Size, Size);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut);
g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, Size, Size);
int topBottomPadding = 0; int leftRightPadding = 0;
if (Size > lnNewWidth + 1)
    leftRightPadding = Convert.ToInt32((Size - lnNewWidth) / 2);
else if (Size > lnNewHeight + 1)
    topBottomPadding = Convert.ToInt32((Size - lnNewHeight) / 2);
g.DrawImage(loBMP, leftRightPadding, topBottomPadding, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bmpOut);
if (bmp != null)
    bmp.Save(ResizedOutput); // C:\Inetpub\vhosts\DomainName\httpdocs\ProductImages\500px\gigabyte_ga_ep45_ds4_profilelarge[1].jpg
bmp.Dispose();
bmpOut.Dispose();
g.Dispose();
loBMP.Dispose();
```

stack trace:

```
[ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.]
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) +377630
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format) +69
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename) +25
   Utilities.ResizeImage(String fileName, String mode) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\batuhanakcay.com\httpdocs\App_Code\Utilities.cs:181
   Link.ToProductImage(String fileName) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\batuhanakcay.com\httpdocs\App_Code\Link.cs:79
   Product.PopulateControls(ProductDetails pd) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\batuhanakcay.com\httpdocs\Product.aspx.cs:37
   Product.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\batuhanakcay.com\httpdocs\Product.aspx.cs:20
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [ASP Net - GDI+ and SAVE JPG or BMP on the server](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t121887-gdi-and-save-jpg-or-bmp-on-the-server.html)

> 99.9% of the time, when using GDI, 'a generic error occured' means that the
>   directory you are trying to save to
>   doesn't have the proper permissions.
>   Typically, you need to make sure that the
>   directory is allowing ASP.NET to
>   modify files.

Did you check the permissions?

Comment: how silly of me, i have been digging through my code for 2 days trying to find what the heck is wrong. you are right, it had to be the first thing i have checked. i just give the user "Plesk IIS WP User (IWAM_plesk(default))" full permission, and it is working. thanks.

Comment: SO is meant to be your second pair of eyes X-)

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: I have fixed the error by disposing the image in Picturebox control that was generated using GDI+.

Answer (score 2):

This error also occurs when you try to save on a network share. The only solution to fix this is to move your bitmap to a memory stream and save it with a file stream to the network share.

Here's an extension method to easily fix this:

```
public static void SaveOnNetworkShare(this System.Drawing.Image aImage, string aFilename, 
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat aImageFormat)
{
  using (System.IO.MemoryStream lMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
  {
    aImage.Save(lMemoryStream, aImageFormat);

    using (System.IO.FileStream lFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(aFilename, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
    {
      lMemoryStream.Position = 0;

      lMemoryStream.CopyTo(lFileStream);
    }
  }      
}
```