# C++ - save image from form to file

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm new in programming Windows Form Application. I want to capture my Windows form (with the function CaptureScreen()) and save it to a file by clicking on a button using the SaveFileDialog. Here my code:

```
private: System::Void CaptureScreen() 
{
    Drawing::Graphics^ myGraphics = this->CreateGraphics();
    memoryImage = gcnew Drawing::Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height, myGraphics);
    Drawing::Graphics^ memoryGraphics = Drawing::Graphics::FromImage(memoryImage);
    memoryGraphics->CopyFromScreen(this->Location.X, this->Location.Y, 0, 0, this->Size);
}

private: System::Void btnSave_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    SaveFileDialog^ saveDiag2 = gcnew SaveFileDialog();
    saveDiag2->Filter = "Dateityp PNG (*.PNG)|*.PNG|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveDiag2->FilterIndex = 1;
    saveDiag2->RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (saveDiag2->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        String^ savePath = saveDiag2->FileName;
        if (saveDiag2->OpenFile() != nullptr)
        {
            try
            { 
                CaptureScreen();
                if (memoryImage != nullptr)
                {
                    memoryImage->Save(savePath, Imaging::ImageFormat::Png);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception^)
            {
                MessageBox::Show("There was a problem saving the file."
                    "Check the file permissions.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I always get the Exception displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `C++-CLI` is the correct tag for this code, also added tag for Windows Forms.

Comment: Could you display the Exception contents, it may indicate you what's wrong. You also can put a breakpoint at beginning of try block for debugging

Comment: That's terribly broken error handling code, never ever display a "it did not work" message.  It is not helpful to anybody, not to you either.  Use the exception object's ToString() method.  Your code is missing `delete memoryImage;`  If you don't then the file stays locked and trying to overwrite it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant is right. You should dispose IDisposible objects. In C++ CLI you can do it with help of msclr::auto_handle smart pointer.

```
#include <msclr/auto_handle.h>

private: System::Void CaptureScreen() 
         {
             msclr::auto_handle<Drawing::Graphics> myGraphics(this->CreateGraphics());
             memoryImage = gcnew Drawing::Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height, myGraphics.get());
             msclr::auto_handle<Drawing::Graphics> memoryGraphics(Drawing::Graphics::FromImage(memoryImage));
             memoryGraphics->CopyFromScreen(this->Location.X, this->Location.Y, 0, 0, this->Size);
         }
```

Also you can retrieve usefull information from Exception object:

```
    catch (Exception^ exception)
    {
        MessageBox::Show("There was a problem saving the file: " + exception->ToString(),
            "Check the file permissions.");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I added `delete memoryImage` after the error handling code as suggested by @Hans Passant. @Dmitriy The exception object produce now following error: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): Error in GDI+.` `at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo Encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)` `at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, Imageformat Format)` `at btnSave_Click(Object Sender, EventArgs e) in Programm.h:Row 548.` Is the error occuring because of saving on a Network Folder. In this how should I handle it?

Comment: You can easily check by saving to local drive. Also you can check permissions. Also look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431301/asp-net-error-on-bitmap-save-exception-0x80004005-a-generic-error-occurred-i) - second answer.