# Can't delete file from server straight after upload it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created fileUpload Controller that posts a file to a server.

```
myControllerName.PostedFile.SaveAs(saveLocation);
```

In case I'm trying to delete the file from the server immediately after the upload finishes, it returns me an exception:

> [IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\RestOFMyFilePath' because it is being used by another process.]

So I've used:

```
GC.Collect(); 
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

I tried to put those lines before and after the functions in my code to locate the specific function that locks the resource. If I put it before the problem, it still occurs, and when it was after it fixes it.

Narrowed it down to

```
somefunctionName(FileUpload myControllerName)
```

Tried to dispose (actively) the resources by

```
iconUploadController.PostedFile.InputStream.Dispose();
iconUploadController.Dispose();
```

and I still get that error.

Another solution I've tried is to create proxy class for fileUpload

FileUpload.cs:

```
public class FileUploadProxy : IDisposable
{
    public FileUpload fileUploadController;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        fileUploadController.Dispose(); 
    }
}
```

So I could use "using" (releases the resources straight after exit the scope) - still didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify how are you saving the file

Comment: Are you running anti-virus on your server? It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've edited the question with how did I upload the file to the server. No Anti-virus. I thought it a complete explanation, Ask me anything if further details will help.

Comment: Try to save the file via a separate file stream like https://stackoverflow.com/a/32908724/3936440 , perhaps the using statements solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, The problem was that inside the "somefunctionName(FileUpload myControllerName)" I had another call to the same file which I've missed:

```
System.Drawing.Image objImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePathOnDisk)
```

The solution:

```
using (System.Drawing.Image objImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePathOnDisk))
{
      //Operation on the objImage.
}
```